# What is Node.js' Connect, Express and "middleware"?

Tags: node.js, middleware

Despite knowing JavaScript quite well, I'm confused what *exactly* these three projects in Node.js ecosystem do. Is it something like Rails' Rack? Can someone please explain?

Comment: I haven't used connect, but [this page](http://howtonode.org/connect-it) sure makes it sound analogous to Rails' Rack. Do you understand what middleware is, outside of the context of Node?

Comment: Honestly, not as much as i would like to. As far as I know it's the layer that does all the pre-app stuff like routing, gzipping, headers, cookies..? Am I right? So does it work in a way that routing to the proper MVC controller/action not inside of the MVC framework (like Rails), but in the middleware?

Comment: See also here http://project70.com/nodejs/understanding-connect-and-middleware/

Comment: THIS WILL CLEAR ALL YOUR DOUBTS AND ANSWER MANY MORE QUERIES THAT YOU HAVE I understand that it's too late (hopefully someone scrolls down...), but reading the following blog article will clear all the questions that you have about Connect, Express and Middleware. It also teaches you a bit about Node.js too.
[http://evanhahn.com/understanding-express/](http://evanhahn.com/understanding-express/)

Comment: @DiegoCaxito Your link is broken.

Answer (score 911, accepted):

[**Update:** As of its 4.0 release, Express no longer uses Connect. However, Express is still compatible with middleware written for Connect. My original answer is below.]

I'm glad you asked about this, because it's definitely a common point of confusion for folks looking at Node.js. Here's my best shot at explaining it:

- Node.js itself offers an [http](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.2/api/all.html#hTTP) module, whose `createServer` method returns an object that you can use to respond to HTTP requests. That object inherits the `http.Server` prototype.
- [Connect](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/) also offers a `createServer` method, which returns an object that inherits an extended version of `http.Server`. Connect's extensions are mainly there to make it easy to plug in [middleware](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki). That's why Connect describes itself as a "middleware framework," and is often analogized to Ruby's Rack.
- [Express](http://expressjs.com/) does to Connect what Connect does to the http module: It offers a `createServer` method that extends Connect's `Server` prototype. So all of the functionality of Connect is there, *plus* view rendering and a handy DSL for describing routes. Ruby's Sinatra is a good analogy.
- Then there are other frameworks that go even further and extend Express! [Zappa](https://github.com/mauricemach/zappa), for instance, which integrates support for CoffeeScript, server-side jQuery, and testing.

Here's a concrete example of what's meant by "middleware": Out of the box, none of the above serves static files for you. But just throw in `connect.static` (a middleware that comes with Connect), configured to point to a directory, and your server will provide access to the files in that directory. Note that Express provides Connect's middlewares also; `express.static` is the same as `connect.static`. (Both were known as `staticProvider` until recently.)

My impression is that most "real" Node.js apps are being developed with Express these days; the features it adds are extremely useful, and all of the lower-level functionality is still there if you want it.

Comment: One thing that upsets me about Connect is that its documentation doesn't seem to acknowledge that Node is more than a HTTP server. "Connect is a middleware framework for Node.js" -- no, "Connect is a middleware framework for Node.js's HTTP server"

Comment: @slim I think you're reading into that too much. The makers of Connect are preeminent Node developers; they're well aware that Node is more than an HTTP server. But it does *have* an HTTP server built in, and Connect is a middleware framework that you can use in your Node.js app.

Comment: Oh I'm sure the makers of Connect are fully aware of that. They couldn't have achieved what they have without a thorough understanding of Node. But the choice of words is confusing for newcomers to Node; and to newcomers to Connect.

Comment: crystal clear, what all answers should strive for. Excellent work Trevor.

Comment: Great explanation. Answers like this help bring new people into the Node.js ecosystem.

For people getting familiar with developing web apps in Node.js, Express is the place to start. To continue the Ruby analogy, Express is comparable to Sinatra. It's particularly great for creating JSON APIs for Ajax client-side apps.

One thing I've found is that once an application hits a certain level of complexity, another layer is needed that is more Rails like. I'm working on [Locomotive](http://locomotivejs.org/) for this purpose, which further layers on top of Express.

Comment: Zappa has not been updated in about a year and no longer works with current versions of node; for those looking to use it now, [ZappaJS](http://zappajs.github.com/zappajs/) is a fork that is under active development and works.

Comment: I would like to say that sails.js is better to start than express.js, especially if you're coming from `ruby` or Php with MVC framework experience.

Comment: The relationships in this answer are wrong now. I posted about the updated relationship : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23957864/390330

Comment: Well I am one of those "Node newbies" and the explanation is great so far but I still didn't quite get, what middleware exactly is. Is it just some kind of Interface, that's implemented, so that the middleware listens for some events and acts on them? I googled arround for a little but couldn't find anything about middleware specificly. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: "Connect also offers" link is gone -> https://github.com/senchalabs/connect

Comment: @Anticom from what I've heard, middlewares are functions that execute lines, then call the next middleware function, and after it returns, they execute a few more lines, then they return. So they're pretty much functions that wrap around other functions. A logging function that simply does console.log('Request received') and ('Request completed') seems like a nice example

Answer (score 178):

The accepted answer is really old (and now wrong). Here's the information (with source) based on the current version of Connect (3.0) / Express (4.0).

### What Node.js comes with

[http](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html) / [https](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html) `createServer` which simply takes a callback(req,res) e.g.

```
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    // respond
    response.write('hello client!');
    response.end();

});

server.listen(3000);
```

### What connect adds

**Middleware** is basically any software that sits between your application code and some low level API. Connect extends the built-in HTTP server functionality and adds a plugin framework. The plugins act as middleware and hence connect is a *middleware framework*

The way it does that is pretty simple ([and in fact the code is really short!](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/a9d71168013454635cf069ff2954977df355979f/lib/proto.js)). As soon as you call `var connect = require('connect'); var app = connect();` you get a function `app` that can:

1. Can handle a request and return a response. This is because you basically get [this function](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/a9d71168013454635cf069ff2954977df355979f/lib/connect.js#L28)
2. Has a member function `.use` ([source](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/a9d71168013454635cf069ff2954977df355979f/lib/proto.js#L62)) to manage *plugins* ([that comes from here](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/a9d71168013454635cf069ff2954977df355979f/lib/proto.js) because of [this simple line of code](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/a9d71168013454635cf069ff2954977df355979f/lib/connect.js#L29)).

Because of 1.) you can do the following :

```
var app = connect();

// Register with http
http.createServer(app)
    .listen(3000);
```

Combine with 2.) and you get:

```
var connect = require('connect');

// Create a connect dispatcher
var app = connect()
      // register a middleware
      .use(function (req, res, next) { next(); });

// Register with http
http.createServer(app)
    .listen(3000);
```

Connect provides a utility function to register itself with `http` so that you don't need to make the call to `http.createServer(app)`. Its called `listen` and the code simply creates a new http server, register's connect as the callback and forwards the arguments to `http.listen`. [From source](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/a9d71168013454635cf069ff2954977df355979f/lib/proto.js#L231-L234)

```
app.listen = function(){
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

So, you can do:

```
var connect = require('connect');

// Create a connect dispatcher and register with http
var app = connect()
          .listen(3000);
console.log('server running on port 3000');
```

It's still your good old `http.createServer` with a plugin framework on top.

### What ExpressJS adds

ExpressJS and connect are parallel projects. Connect is *just* a middleware framework, with a nice `use` function. *Express does not depend on Connect* ([see package.json](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/311e83e591a149a7549bab543dfd126d3223f7fd/package.json#L49-L68)). However it does the everything that connect does i.e:

1. Can be registered with `createServer` like connect since it too is just a function that can take a `req`/`res` pair ([source](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/311e83e591a149a7549bab543dfd126d3223f7fd/lib/express.js#L27)).
2. A [use function to register middleware](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/311e83e591a149a7549bab543dfd126d3223f7fd/lib/application.js#L174).
3. A utility `listen` function to [register itself with http](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/311e83e591a149a7549bab543dfd126d3223f7fd/lib/application.js#L538-L541)

In addition to what connect provides (which express duplicates), it has a bunch of more features. e.g.

1. Has [view engine support](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/311e83e591a149a7549bab543dfd126d3223f7fd/lib/application.js#L463).
2. Has top level [verbs (get/post etc.) for its router](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/311e83e591a149a7549bab543dfd126d3223f7fd/lib/application.js#L408-L409).
3. Has [application settings](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/311e83e591a149a7549bab543dfd126d3223f7fd/lib/application.js#L307) support.

### The middleware is *shared*

The `use` function of ExpressJS *and* connect is compatible and therefore the *middleware is shared*. Both are middleware frameworks, express just has more than *a simple middleware framework*.

## Which one should you use?

My opinion: you are informed enough ^based on above^ to make your own choice.

- Use `http.createServer` if you are creating something like connect / expressjs from scratch.
- Use connect if you are authoring middleware, testing protocols etc. since it is a nice abstraction on top of `http.createServer`
- Use ExpressJS if you are authoring websites.

Most people should just use ExpressJS.

## What's wrong about the accepted answer

These might have been true as some point in time, but wrong now:

> that inherits an extended version of http.Server

Wrong. It doesn't extend it and as you have seen ... *uses it*

> Express does to Connect what Connect does to the http module

Express 4.0 doesn't even depend on connect. [see the current package.json dependencies section](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/311e83e591a149a7549bab543dfd126d3223f7fd/package.json#L49-L68)

Comment: you say gives you the ability to handle a request and return a response but people say that Express is really the web server...I'm confused.  Wouldn't sending a response back need web server capability (like Express)?

Comment: good stuff, thanks!  very helpful...especially not knowing that connect really is what provides the routing, and express just inherits that, it isn't the sole/source provider of routing.  And the use cases at the end are helpful because I assumed I'd have to use connect AND express but really all you need to use is express for web apps so this cleared a huge thing up for me.  You don't install both, you install one or the other!

Comment: Your answer should be on top. when I read the accepted answer, I upvoted it. But after reading your answer...naahhh

Answer (score 71):

### node.js

Node.js is a javascript motor for the server side.
In addition to all the js capabilities, it includes networking capabilities (like HTTP), and access to the file system.
This is different from client-side js where the networking tasks are monopolized by the browser, and access to the file system is forbidden for security reasons.

### node.js as a web server: express

Something that runs in the server, understands HTTP and can access files sounds like a web server. But it isn't one.
To make node.js behave like a web server one has to program it: handle the incoming HTTP requests and provide the appropriate responses.
This is what Express does: it's the implementation of a web server in js.
Thus, implementing a web site is like configuring Express routes, and programming the site's specific features.

### Middleware and Connect

Serving pages involves a number of tasks. Many of those tasks are well known and very common, so node's [Connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) module (one of the many modules available to run under node) implements those tasks.
See the current impressing offering:

- **logger**           request logger with custom format support
- **csrf**             Cross-site request forgery protection
- **compress**         Gzip compression middleware
- **basicAuth**        basic http authentication
- **bodyParser**       extensible request body parser
- **json**             application/json parser
- **urlencoded**       application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
- **multipart**        multipart/form-data parser
- **timeout**          request timeouts
- **cookieParser**     cookie parser
- **session**          session management support with bundled MemoryStore
- **cookieSession**    cookie-based session support
- **methodOverride**   faux HTTP method support
- **responseTime**     calculates response-time and exposes via X-Response-Time
- **staticCache**      memory cache layer for the static() middleware
- **static**           streaming static file server supporting Range and more
- **directory**        directory listing middleware
- **vhost**            virtual host sub-domain mapping middleware
- **favicon**          efficient favicon server (with default icon)
- **limit**            limit the bytesize of request bodies
- **query**            automatic querystring parser, populating req.query
- **errorHandler**     flexible error handler

Connect is the framework and through it you can pick the (sub)modules you need.
The [Contrib Middleware](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki) page enumerates a long list of additional *middlewares*.
Express itself comes with the most common Connect middlewares.

### What to do?

Install node.js.
Node comes with *npm*, the *node package manager*.
The command `npm install -g express` will download and install express globally (check the [express guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html)).
Running `express foo` in a command line (not in node) will create a ready-to-run application named foo. Change to its (newly created) directory and run it with node with the command `node <appname>`, then open `http://localhost:3000` and see.
Now you are in.

Comment: great reply thanks.  This is the kind of simple crap every blog post misses, the simple setup which can be ??? if you've never done it before.  Yea it's simple when you have already done it but you have no clue how to start for the FIRST time!  I hate it when devs overlook that in blog posts, it's essential.  I don't want to have to FIND another blog post just to find setup.  Just provide a link to another blog post in your other posts, that's extremely helpful so I don't have to hunt around for one.  Save me the hunting trip!

Comment: Express 4.0.0 need to do sudo npm install -g express-generator

Comment: @getsetbro you just mean 'npm install' to install the dependencies.

Answer (score 16):

Connect offers a "higher level" APIs for common HTTP server functionality like session management, authentication, logging and more. Express is built on top of Connect with advanced  (Sinatra like) functionality.

Answer (score 0):

`Node.js` itself offers an HTTP module, whose *createServer* method returns an object that you can use to respond to HTTP requests. That object inherits the `http.Server` prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Related information, especially if you are using NTVS for working with the Visual Studio IDE. The NTVS adds both NodeJS and Express tools, scaffolding, project templates to Visual Studio 2012, 2013.

Also, the verbiage that calls ExpressJS or Connect as a "WebServer" is incorrect. You can create a basic WebServer with or without them. A basic NodeJS program can also use the http module to handle http requests, Thus becoming a rudimentary web server.

Answer (score 0):

middleware as the name suggests actually middleware is sit between middle.. middle of what? middle of request and response..[how request,response,express server sit in express app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98HUh.png) 
in this picture you can see requests are coming from client then the express server server serves those requests.. then lets dig deeper.. actually we can divide this whole express server's whole task in to small seperate tasks like in this way.
[how middleware sit between request and response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0tG1.png) small chunk of server parts doing some particular task and passed request to next one.. finally doing all the tasks response has been made..
all middle ware can access request object,response object and next function of request response cycle..

this is good example for explaining middleware in express [youtube video for middleware](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBkOz9WLZRM&t=543s)

Answer (score 0):

Middleware are special functions that run between or in the middle of request comming in & response going out from our api.
For example we use
`app.use((req, res, next)=>{ }`

here next work as a middleware between req and res in express js

Answer (score -6):

## The stupid simple answer

Connect and Express are web servers for nodejs. Unlike Apache and IIS, they can both use the same modules, referred to as "middleware".