# why use http.createSever in express app?

Tags: node.js, express

I found in express api documentation, this is how one creates new express server

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.listen(3000);
```

it works properly but when you create a new app using express by default it generate following code to create new server

```
 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();
    http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
      console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
    });
```

can someone explain me why express using http createServer method here.

Comment: http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.listen should explain it fairly well. Also, "*Application function*" and "*Socket.IO compatibility*" in the [2.x to 3.x migration wiki](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x).

Comment: *"when you create a new app using express by default it generate following code to create new server"*: What editor do you use?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that Express uses Node's http module on it's core and that's why you craete your Express application like that.

Check this for more info.

[What is Node.js' Connect, Express and "middleware"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284340/what-is-node-js-connect-express-and-middleware)