# ExpressJS and CoffeeScript class inheritance

Tags: inheritance, express, coffeescript

With [`CoffeeScript`](http://coffeescript.org/) I can extend node's [`http.Server`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server) class:

```
{Server} = require 'http'
class MyServer extends Server
  foo: 'bar'
myserver = new MyServer
console.log myserver.foo # 'bar'

class MyServer2 extends MyServer
  constructor: -> super()
myserver2 = new MyServer2
myserver.listen 3000
```

If I have correctly understood [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284340/what-is-node-js-connect-express-and-middleware), [`express`](http://expressjs.com/) extends [`connect`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) which in turn extends `http.Server`. But the following have some inheritance problems:

```
Express = require 'express'
class MyApp extends Express
  foo: 'bar'
myapp = new MyApp
console.log myapp.foo # undefined

class MyApp2 extends MyApp
  constructor: -> super()
myapp2 = new MyApp2
console.log myapp2 # {}
myapp2.listen 3000 # throws TypeError
```

When `listen` is called it throws the following error because `myapp2` is an empty object `{}` and doesn't have the `listen` method:

```
TypeError: Object #<MyApp2> has no method 'listen'
```

How can I use `express` in an Object Oriented Way with `CoffeeScript`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can totally do it. Just remove those `()` :

```
express = require 'express'
class MyApp extends express
myapp = new MyApp
myapp.listen 3000
```

`express` now represents a class, so maybe you should call it `Express` instead, to stick with CoffeeScript's guidelines. You see, `express()` returns you an instance of a descendant of `http.Server`, not a descendant class, so you were trying to extend a server instance. CoffeeScript allows direct usage of JS prototypes, and that's what you accidentally did. So, the first two lines should look like this:

```
Express = require 'express'
class MyApp extends Express
```

Comment: Thanks! But I found more problems, I have updated the question with them :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't extend from express or server, because it's a function not a class. You can test this by using:

`console.log(typeof express);`