# How do I parse raw data on request?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a form for submitting `post data` to a database with Ajax that looks like this:

```
function markAsRead(id) {
    console.log('Triggered');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/admin/assessment.html',
        data: id,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.error) {
                console.log('We had an error.');
            } else if (data.success) {
                console.log('Marker updated.');
            }
        }
    })
}

(function() {
    var element = document.getElementsByName('markAsRead');
    for(var i = 0; i < element.length; i += 1) {
        element[i].addEventListener('click', function(e)  { e.preventDefault;
            markAsRead(this.getAttribute('data-value'));
        });
    }
})();
```

I have multiple Anchors on my page that look like this for example:

```
<a href="#" name="markAsRead" data-value="5135135">Mark As Read</a>
```

I'm just wondering on the `Node.js` side of things, how might I parse that data, I Tried:

```
var id = req.body.markAsRead;

  console.log('Data is ' + id);
```

But it just says undefined. Any information would be great on how to parse this request data. Thanks! (The `Anchor` is not inside any form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should be POSTing data from the client with named parameters, or something more structured than a string.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/admin/assessment.html',
    data: { id: id },
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.error) {
            console.log('We had an error.');
        } else if (data.success) {
            console.log('Marker updated.');
        }
    }
})
```

Second, when you parse the req.body on the node side, you're parsing the string that is sent as the request body, which includes your parameters **{ id: 'somevalue' }**.  You could parse this yourself, but I'm guessing you're using something like **express** or another abstraction on top of node's http.Server implementation that supports a [middleware stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284340/what-is-node-js-connect-express-and-middleware).  I recommend using the [connect bodyParser()](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/bodyParser.html) middleware, which will convert the req.body string into an object with properties that were posted.  This will make **req.body.id** available to you in your request handler in node.