# in express how multiple callback works in app.get

Tags: node.js, express, asynccallback

I am newbie in node so please forgive me if i am not getting obvious. 
In node.js express application for app.get function we typically pass route and view as parameters
e.g.

```
app.get('/users', user.list);
```

but in [passport-google example](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google/blob/master/examples/signon/app.js) I found that they are calling it as

```
app.get('/users', ensureAuthenticated, user.list);
```

where ensureAuthenticated is a function

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
    res.redirect('/login')
}
```

In short this means there are multiple callbacks which while running are called in series. i tried adding couple of more functions to make it look like

```
app.get('/users', ensureAuthenticated, dummy1, dummy2, user.list);
```

and i found ensureAuthenticated, dummy1, dummy2, user.list is getting called in series.

for my specific requirement i find calling functions sequentially in above form is quite elegant solution rather that using async series. can somebody explain me how it really works and how i can implement similar functionality in general.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284340/what-is-node-js-connect-express-and-middleware

Answer (score 17):

In Express, each argument after the path is called in sequence.  Usually, this is a way of implementing middleware (as you can see in the example you provided).

```
app.get('/users', middleware1, middleware2, middleware3, processRequest);

function middleware1(req, res, next){
    // perform middleware function e.g. check if user is authenticated

    next();  // move on to the next middleware

    // or

    next(err);  // trigger error handler, usually to serve error page e.g. 403, 501 etc
}
```

Comment: Is there any way of passing some data to the next callback, like... say `sessionAccount`?

Comment: @Victor Yes, just append the data to the `req` object (`req.sessionAccount = ...`).

Comment: @Jonas  thank you very much! I tried it myself before you answered and I found out it worked

Comment: How can I pass a custom parameter in middleware function?

Comment: @KetavChotaliya How is that different than what victor asked (and was answered by Jonas)?