# How to call a server-side NodeJS function using client-side JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, glitch-framework

I'm working on creating a basic login system, and since the server-side uses NodeJS, but client-side doesn't. I have to make any calls that use NPM packages on the server side. The issue is I have no clue how to call a server-side NodeJS function from the Client-Side JavaScript. Basically I wan't to be able to call a function that's stored on the server from the client browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a route in your nodejs application like so:

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
 // Your function to be called goes here.
});
```

Now you can call this code from your client side javascript using ajax. Like this:

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'GET'
 url: 'http://localhost:8000/users',
 success: function(response) { 
  console.log(response);
 },
 error: function(xhr, status, err) {
   console.log(xhr.responseText);
 }
});
```

Comment: I see, can I put multiple functions inside the app.get, or do I need to change the '/users' for each function?

Comment: You can pass any number of callbacks to the routes like app.get('/users', cb1, cb2, ...). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26894101/6412356) answer has given a good clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Create a REST API and map the request parameters to the specific function calls you need to use.  See [this tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/olatundegaruba/nodejs-restful-apis-in-10-minutes-q0sgsfhbd) on creating REST APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You do this by calling APIs on the server (a specific url that will to some specific work).In JS you need ajax. [Have a look here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

```
//url be the api like '/api/something/'
$("button").click(function(){
  $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
    // your response
  }});
});
```

in Node we have [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) that will do the same
example

```
axios.post('api/tobackend/function',{user:'a',password:'b'})
     .then((res)=>console.log('response from server'))
```

in backed you might need route to handle the request.

```
router.post('api/tobackend/function',(reqs,resp)=>{console.log('backend')})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. With Socket.io
2. in JS

   `let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); xhr.open('GET', '/user/sessionDestroy'); xhr.send();`

In Node.JS