# Web application middleware understanding

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, web-applications

I'm a beginner with node.js and i'm trying to build my first web application.
However i want to get good practices from the begining.

So I learn some guide to well organize my code. 
I went on MVC pattern that i understand well. But in the guides I read besides the models, views qnd controllers section there was a middleware section.
I can't see the differences between middleware and controllers
Here is the guide: http://www.terlici.com/2014/08/25/best-practices-express-structure.html

Can somebody explain me what is the purpsoe of using middlewares precisely, and the difference between middlewares and controllers precisely ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided says it best:

> The purpose of a middleware is to extract a common controller code,
>   which should be executed on multiple requests and usually modifies the
>   request and/or the response objects.

So basically, if you have functionality that is shared between controllers you put it in your middleware.

It's explained in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284340/what-is-node-js-connect-express-and-middleware?rq=1).