# Difference between Express and Connect npm packages

Tags: node.js, express, npm, node.js-connect

I have been using express webservers since I started working on Node.js and a few days ago I came across this new (to me) web server, called connect.

Can anyone point out, what are the differences between the [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) and [connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect)? When should we use connect and when to go for express?

As far as I know, both are web-servers based on HTTP module of Node.js.

Which one should go for?

Please be more descriptive and post some useful links to start with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Node.js' Connect, Express and "middleware"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284340/what-is-node-js-connect-express-and-middleware)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In a nutshell, connect provides the use of middlewares in your application, everything connect can do, express can do it also, but express adds other useful things such as a view engine...
see [here](http://evanhahn.com/understanding-express/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284340/what-is-node-js-connect-express-and-middleware) to help you decide.

Comment: Before `4.x` express was built on top of connect.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny And afterwards?

Answer (score -2):

1.Node.js
Node.js has a simple http/https based create server method with a callback (arguments - req/res).

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.write('server up');
}
```

2.Connect.js 
Connect is basically middleware framework similar to Express. Connect extends the built-in http server functionality using which you can handle req and res objects, and it also helps you use "plugins" using the .use method.