# How to get parameter from URL in express without getting into request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use('/', anyroute);

// in anyroute file
router.route('/:id').get(controlFunction)

controlFunction(req, res, res)=> {
// Here we can get the "id" from the variable with req.param.id
}
```

but I want to use the "id" before getting into this controller function. Like this

```
modifyFunction(userId)=> {
// Do something with the userId
}

router.route('/:id').get(modifyFunction(id), controlFunction)
```

Is it possible in express and javascript to retrieve the 'id' from `url` and use in `modifyFunction(id)` before getting into the request.

In an express middleware req and res variables are transferred from one middleware to next. But I created a function function(type, id) which returns a middleware function(req, res, next). in this function(type, id) type parameter will be passed manually and id from URL.

```
router
  .route('/all-contacts/:id')
  .get(authController.isLoggedIn, viewController.getAxiosConfig('contactNameEmail', id), viewController.getAllContact);  

exports.getAxiosConfig = (type, id) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    const config = axiosConfig(type, id);
    const accessToken = req.cookies.access_token;
    const tokenArray = config.headers.Authorization.split(' ');
    tokenArray.splice(1, 1, accessToken);
    const newToken = tokenArray.join(' ');
    config.headers.Authorization = newToken;
    req.config = config;
    next();
  };
};
exports.getAllContact = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  // const token = req.cookies.access_token;
  // console.log(token);
  // const config = axiosConfig('contactNameEmail');
  req.config.method = 'GET';
  // const tokenArray = config.headers.Authorization.split(' ');
  // tokenArray.splice(1, 1, token);
  // const newToken = tokenArray.join(' ');
  // config.headers.Authorization = newToken;
  const contacts = await axios(req.config);
  console.log(req.config);

  const { data } = contacts;
  res.status(200).render('contactList', {
    title: 'All contacts',
    data
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you explain more about your final goal? I don't see why you would want to do that. Do you mean that you want to create some middleware in which to do something with that ID?

Comment: Yes I want to create a middleware to get rid of reusing same code in my every route handler function.

Comment: Do you know how to write a middleware? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284340/what-is-node-js-connect-express-and-middleware?r=SearchResults

Comment: In an express middleware req and res variables are transferred from one middleware to next. But I created a function function(type, id) which returns a middleware function(req, res, next). in this function(type, id) type parameter will be passed manually and id from URL.

Comment: So basically you want to get the I'd from the URL?

Comment: Yes, from front-end using javascript and from back-end using express.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Although I haven't found my answer but that link help me solve my problem. It's Ok now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the ID in the middleware, which is called before the route handler.